# when no matching results in first array how to load second array and search in devbridge autocomplete

Tags: jquery, arrays, autocomplete

I have two array like this

```
  var fruits = [
   { value: 'Apple',id: '123'},
   { value: 'Pear', id: '543' },
   { value: 'Carrot', id: '123' }, 
   ];

   var vegetables= [
   { value: 'Brinj',id: '111'},
   { value: 'Chilli', id: '222' },
   { value: 'CauliFlo', id: '333' }, 
];
```

but default i load first array in devbridge autocomplete like this

```
erpjs(Pid).devbridgeAutocomplete({
            lookup: fruits,          
            minChars: 0,
});
```

while i am searching if first array value is not there means it should load second array is it possible in devbridge autocomplete?

Comment: Try like this:- `erpjs(Pid).devbridgeAutocomplete({
            lookup: $.merge(fruits, vegetables),          
            minChars: 0,
});`

Comment: bro could not merge, if first array has no result means then only second array should load

Comment: Ok try this:- `erpjs(Pid).devbridgeAutocomplete({ lookup: ($.isEmptyObject(fruits)) ? fruits : vegetables, minChars: 0, });`

Comment: sorry bro, its not working

Comment: any error you are getting when using this code?

Comment: no error bro. concept is there are two array with different array. first we load one array in autocomplete.now i am searching in autocomplete it has no result means it should take value from second array

Comment: var fruits = [   { value: 'Apple']; var Vegetables= [   { value: 'Apple22']; now i am searching like Apple2 this time it should get from second array becoz it contains in vegetable array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162900/discussion-between-dhasarathan-t-and-alive-to-die).